# How do I convert java.sql.Array to List<MyCustomEnum>?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, java-8

I have `rs.getArray("lang");` which is `java.sql.Array` and the `lang` field is `character varying[]`. I want to convert it to `List<MyEnumLanguage>`. As an example I have `{fr_FR,en_US}` and I have used the following code to convert that my IDE didn't show any errors

```
List<MyEnumLanguage> myEnumLanguageList = (List<MyEnumLanguage>) rs.getArray("lang");
```

but it throws an exception `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray cannot be cast to java.util.List`.

My `MyEnumLanguage` is like:

```
public enum MyEnumLanguage {
    en_US {
        public String getCode() { return "en_US" }
    },
    de_DE {
        public String getCode() { return "de_DE" }
    };

    private MyEnumLanguage() {
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't, you map it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast an array to List. Your IDE does not show any arror because casting happens on runtime.

Instead, you should use `Arrays.asList(array)` method, which returns a list containing all the elements of the array. 
Note that if you want to *map* the elements of the array to another type, you could easily do that with streams. Example:

```
List<MyEnumLanguage> myEnumLanguageList = Arrays.asList(rs.getArray("lang"))
                .stream()
                .map(arrayElement -> convertToMyEnumLanguage(arrayElement))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `convertToMyEnumLanguage()` takes an element of your array and returns the corresponding `MyEnumLanguage`.

Take a look at this post:  https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/

**UPDATE**

Initially I missread the question. You have to first convert your PgArray to a normal java array, before you can use it in Arrays.asList().

This can be done using `PgArray.getArray()` method, and then cast the returned object to an array of the pgArray's containing type.

**UPDATE 2**

Improved example:

First of all you should define your enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnumLanguage {

    en_US("en_US"),
    de_DE("de_DE");

    private final String code;

    private MyEnumLanguage(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static MyEnumLanguage getEnumByCode(String code) {
        if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        for(MyEnumLanguage e : values()) {
            if(e.getCode().equals(code)) {
                return e;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to map your pgArray to a List:

```
Array pgArray = rs.getArray("lang");
String[] langJavaArray = (String[]) pgArray.getArray(); //this returns an Object, so we cast it to a String array

List<MyEnumLanguage> myEnumLanguageList =
        Arrays.stream(langJavaArray)
        .map(MyEnumLanguage::getEnumByCode)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
;
```

Please note that the mapping function does not check for nulls. So if a wrong codes are passed, your list will contain nulls. If this is not the desired result, you have to perform the appropriate checks and handle null cases in your map function.

Comment: Arrays.asList() takes a java language array as a parameter, which does not have any similarities to a java.sql.Array. Apart from that, you either need to stream() the list, or use Arrays.stream().

Comment: @mtj you're right, i missread the question and updated my answer. As for the stream() method, I just forgot it!